# Prove that $g(A)$ is an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that if $\lambda$ **is not** an eigenvalue of $A$ then $A-\lambda I$ is invertible. Moreover, for $g(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$, prove that if $g(x)$ doesn't have a root which equals to one of $A$ eigenvalues then $g(A)$ is invertible.

For the first question, if there was $v\ne 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I)(v) = 0$ then $\lambda$ was an eigenvalue of $A$, in contrary to the assumption it's not.

Therefore, only the trivial solution exists and therefore $A$ is invertible.

I got trouble with the second question. I am guessing Cayley–Hamilton theorem may take part here.

Comment: The second question is under the assumption that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by the second question?  That $g$ does not vanish at any eigenvalue of $A$?  You did not define $\lambda$.

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues of $A$, what are the eigenvalues of $A^2$? Of $A^3$? Of $2A^3-4A^2+I$? Of $g(x)$?

Comment: @ajotatxe, the answer is yes.

Comment: I've edited the second question as it wasn't totally clear.

Comment: hint: factorize $g$ into linear factors and use the previous result.

Comment: Is $g$ any complex valued function or must it be polynomial?

Comment: @mathreadler, must be a polynomial

Comment: @user251257, I think you're suggestion is the simplest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question only requires the definition of an eigenvalue.

For the second one, since $g\in \mathbb{C}[X],  g(X)=c\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(X-\lambda_i)$ so $g(A)=c\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(A-\lambda_i I)$.

And since the product of invertible matrices is invertible, you can conclude using the first point.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g(X) = c\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n(X-\lambda_i)$?

Comment: You're right, corrected, but as long as $c\ne0$, it does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use eigen decomposition.

If A is diagonalizable matrix then $ A = Q^{-1} \Lambda Q $ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix with eigevalues on the diagonal.

Then $ A^k = Q^{-1} \Lambda^k Q $ and

$g(A) = Q^{-1} g(\Lambda) Q $.

$g(\Lambda)$ is diagonal matrix with $g(\lambda_i)$ elements. From this place your proposition is easy to prove.

If A is not diagonalizable then the approach is the same but $\Lambda$ is composed of blocks like this:

$$ 
\begin{array}{lcl} \lambda & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1  & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda &  ... & 0  \\ ... \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & \lambda \end{array}
$$

In this case $f(\Lambda)$ calculates just a bit harder.

Comment: If not, you have to deal with blocks described above. The $g(A)=Q^{−1}g(\Lambda)Q$ still holds. And $g(\Lambda)$ can be calculated just a bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$g(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]\implies \sigma\left(g(A)\right)=\{g(\lambda):\lambda\in \sigma(A)\}$$ where $\sigma(\cdot)$ denotes the spectrum, i.e. collection of eigenvalues of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

By Brauers Theorem ( Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson ) subtracting by $\lambda {\bf I}$ will reduce all eigenvalues by $\lambda$ and if none equals $\lambda$ means each of them will become non-zero.